# Extjs4 tree panel borrow from grid panel

Tags: grid, treepanel, extjs4.1

I was trying to implement lockable feature on tree.Panel so i borrowed from grid.Panel

```
Ext.tree.Panel(Ext.grid.Panel, ['bothCfgCopy','normalCfgCopy','lockedCfgCopy']);
```

but now my grid columns are objects i.e a column.$className on a tree.Panel would return an object because they have been transformed.
How do i hide columns now as all functionality such as hide(), setVisible() have been lost ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It might not still be relevant, but [here's](https://github.com/matsbryntse/ExtJS4-Lockable-Tree/branches) an example of a buffering locking grid.

You can set buffering to false and use as is, or you can use it as a guideline for you current implementation.